# Random integer generating

Tags: python, random, statistics, distribution

I've faced with the curious question. Maybe someone could guide me to relevant literature.

So, in Python, I've created this method, which appends random integers to set until repeated value occurs. When a generated integer is not unique for particularly set, method brakes:

```
import random

def count_no_repeat(i,j):
    random_set = set()
    while True:
        new_number = random.randint(i,j)
        if new_number in random_set:
            break
        random_set.add(new_number)
    return len(random_set) + 1
```

Then, I've repeated this method thousand times to count: *how much steps it needs to generate non-been-before value*

```
stats = []
for _ in range(1000):
    stats.append(count_no_repeat(1,n))
```

> n - there is upper bound for integer generator.

And got such results:
for n = 100:
[image: n equals 100]

for n = 1000:
[image: n equals 1000]

for n = 10000:
[image: n equals 10000]

for n = 100000:
[image: n equals 100000]

So, for this experiment median:

- grows relatively slow;
- stays on the place on the plot (that also true for a 10'000-times experiment);

Who can help, and say, why this is so?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be a simulation of birthday attack.

Comment: Thanks for embedding img's

Comment: Is your question why is this happening?

Comment: Can you clarify your question or topic for which you need help?

Comment: This is probably better asked on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/), although you'll also likely get a 'mathier' answer there.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem for an explanation of what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're computing PDF of the generalized birthday problem. It is basically all here in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem. Only problem is Wiki page is talking about CDF of the problem (see first graph here), you're sampling PDF, values of p(n, k) - p(n, k-1). Here is the your plot of sampling (blue) vs PDF (orange), if you need code just tell me

[image]

UPDATE

Anyway, better put code here so it is not lost. All factorials are computed as Gamma functions, and expression for pbar/p is done via logarithms, avoiding overflows, so there are calls to logarithm of Gamma function, lgamma.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import random

def pbar(k, n): # as in wiki article, computed via log/exp
    l = 0
    try:
        l = math.lgamma(n + 1)  - math.lgamma(n - k + 1) - k*math.log(n)
    except ValueError:
        l = -50
    return math.exp(l)

def p(k, n):
    return 1.0 - pbar(k, n)

def count_no_repeat(i, j): # original sampling code
    random_set = set()
    while True:
        new_number = random.randint(i,j)
        if new_number in random_set:
            break
        random_set.add(new_number)
    return len(random_set) + 1

# 100 of numbers, 1mln of samples
n = 100
N = 1000000
stats = np.zeros(n+2, dtype = np.float32)
meds  = []

for _ in range(0, N):
    q = count_no_repeat(1, n)
    stats[q] += 1
    meds.append(q)

print(np.median(meds))

stats /= float(N)
x = np.linspace(0, n+1, n+2)

# computing PDF
z = []
for k in x:
    if k == 0:
        z.append(0)
    else:
        z.append(p(k, n) - p(k-1, n))

plt.plot(x, stats, 'o')
plt.plot(x, z)
plt.show()
```